# Does there exist ini parser that support lists and files without sections in python?

Tags: python, ini

I am new to python, and i need to read ini file with data lists:

```
list[] = 1
list[] = 2 
list[] = 3
```

and files without sections. I know about ConfigParser module, i saw huge amount of hacks to make it wotk with those things, but i do not want to write all this bullshit in my code. I just want *normal* library that is able to do that itself.

Could you please advice some module, that is able to handle work with ini files please?

Comment: That is not an `INI` format.

Comment: Why do you want it that way?

Comment: @Amadan rlly? It is used over years in C, javascript, PHP, Perl. On windows & linux. First time i see those things are not supported - python, in module that even is not able to read sectionless file :/

Comment: @VincentBeltman because i need to work with configs from other platforms, that work that way

Comment: What I'm saying is that arrays in the form that you are showing is a feature of PHP specifically (since it assigns to array elements on `array[]=...` syntax). Most other libraries will not appreciate multiple keys with same name. I have not seen this format anywhere else, unless it was implemented specifically to accommodate PHP-style serialisation. I challenge you to find another parser library outside of PHP that supports it. You can find common features of INI files in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file); notice how `name[]` form is not listed.

Comment: I heard about another inni-parser called iniparse. https://code.google.com/p/iniparse/ Maybe this one helps.

Comment: @Amadan ok, agreed. Really believed that was exact format of ini. Just have read the specs.

Comment: @VincentBeltman as i understand it provides not just dictionary, but property-alike access.

Comment: To be sure, those aren't the specs; I don't think INI file has specs. But those are the commonly implemented features, that most parsers will support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "INI"-File syntax has no standard, most libraries reinvent some common conventions. And IMHO they are all bad (especially ConfigParser). I propose to use JSON instead of INI-Files. If it's an interchange between different plattforms use the respective stdlibs to convert from "ini" to "json" and export it to python as json.

As metioned by Amadan in the comments below, YAML may even be better, but i suggested json, because it's supported in python's stdlib where yaml (afaik) isn't, at least in 2.x.

Comment: Or YAML. It's nicer for humans, very similar to INI in form, more powerful than JSON; the only downside is that Python does not natively support it, and needs a library.

Comment: If it is gonna be a configuration file, JSON will be harder to read. Consider using YAML instead

Comment: @VincentBeltman Yeah, just has adviced to collegues to use YAML, as JSON is hard to maintain by hands for them.. they are happy. thanks!